# Magento: product collection from a sepecific category and its subcategories

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I tried on different forums and find following code helpful for me, but it isn't returning anything for me.

```
    $limit = ($limit == 0) ? 50 : $limit;
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat_id);

    $category->setIsAnchor(1);

    $products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter("status", array("eq" => 1))
            ->addAttributeToFilter("visibility", array("eq" => 1))
            ->setPageSize($limit)
            ->addCategoryFilter($category)
            ->load();
```

the `$products` are always zero length.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we need to set the `storeId` for getting collection w.r.t category. I used following code

```
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat_id);

    $products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
            ->setStoreId(1)
            ->setPageSize($limit)
            ->addAttributeToFilter(
                    'status',
                    array('eq' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
            )
            ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility',
                    Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
            ->addCategoryFilter($category);
```